# Gradle: how do I depend on the resources task object?

Tags: gradle

In a java war project, I have this code, as from http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html to make sure some directories are created.

```
task resources << {
    mkdir "generated"
}

task acct(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn resources
    // ...
}
```

With this, the build fails:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':acct'.
> Cannot convert org.gradle.api.internal.resources.DefaultResourceHandler@1d65e511 to
a task.
  The following types/formats are supported:
    - A String or CharSequence task name or path
    - A Task instance
    - A Buildable instance
    - A TaskDependency instance
    - A Closure instance that returns any of the above types
    - A Callable instance that returns any of the above types
    - An Iterable, Collection, Map or array instance that contains any of the above types
```

I thought I was using a task instance (2nd item in the above supported list) if I don't use the quotes.

If I use `"resource"` in quotes, it works. If I rename the task to just `res`, it works without quotes as well; as per http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies

Why is that and what is the recommended way of declaring this dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources` will resolve to `project.resources`. To reference the task, you can use `tasks.resources` or (as you said) `"resources"`.

Comment: Why is resource treated differently than res?

Comment: Because there is a `project.resources` property (see `Project` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html)), but there is no `project.res` property.